# How do I install software with an RPM (cx_Oracle) onto CentOS 6?

Tags: python-2.7, centos, yum, cx-oracle, centos6

I have the RPM for a software module that I want to install onto a CentOS 6 system.  I have installed this RPM into the yum database via the command 'rpm -ivh '.  My understanding is that now the RPM can be used to install the module via 'yum install ' but this hasn't worked, i.e. I get a "nothing to install" message when I try that.  So I must not be doing something right?  Can anyone advise?

FYI here's what I've tried so far:

```
$ rpm -ivh cx_Oracle-5.1.2-11g-py27-1.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:cx_Oracle              ########################################### [100%]

$ yum search cx_Oracle
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ash.fastserv.com
 * extras: mirror.symnds.com
 * updates: ftp.linux.ncsu.edu
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 3.5 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 3.5 kB     00:00
============================ N/S Matched: cx_Oracle ============================
cx_Oracle.x86_64 : Python interface to Oracle

$ yum install cx_Oracle
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ash.fastserv.com
 * extras: mirror.symnds.com
 * updates: ftp.linux.ncsu.edu
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 3.5 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 3.5 kB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
Nothing to do

$ yum update cx_Oracle
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ash.fastserv.com
 * extras: mirror.symnds.com
 * updates: ftp.linux.ncsu.edu
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 3.5 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 3.5 kB     00:00
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions, insight, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have already installed the package. You used rpm to install cx_Oracle-5.1.2-11g-py27-1.x86_64.rpm. The "cx_Oracle.x86_64" that `yum search cx_Oracle` reports is the very one that you installed on your machine via your rpm command.